# Java Generics: Require generic to be subclass of a certain type

Tags: java, generics

I have an abstract generic class:

```
public abstract class AbstractMessageHandler<T extends AbstractMessageHandler>
{
    public abstract List<String> getTypesOfMessages();
    public abstract void handleMessage(String message, CometClient client);

    public T setResponseValues(AbstractMessage request, T response )
    {
        response.setCompanyId(request.getCompanyId());
        response.setMessageGroup(request.getMessageGroup());
        response.setUserId(request.getUserId());
        response.setTimeStamp(AbstractMessage.getCurrentTimeStamp());

        return response;
    }
}
```

I need the generic subclass to be a subclass of this class. In otherwords, the generic must be a subclass of AbstractMessageHandler. This however gives me compilation issues. Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Post the compiler error. And, hopefully, you really only want to require a generic subclass, `T`, to be that of the `interface` that `AbstractMessageHandler` theoretically implements, which I imagine is named `MessageHandler`. Relatedly, the `setResponseValues` should most likely take as its parameter a `Message` and not `AbstractMessage`. These are unnecessarily limiting requirements, unless there is simply no `interface` that they implement.

Comment: Without context, I would imagine that the AbstractMessageHandler in your type constraint itself requires a type argument. Are you sure this is the best design for your problem?

Or did you mean `AbstractMessageHandler<T extends AbstractMessage>?`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to follow the example of the Enum class:

```
public abstract class AbstractMessageHandler<T extends AbstractMessageHandler<T>>
```

Comment: I disagree. I don't see any type benefit of this over `<T extends AbstractMessageHandler<?>>` given the code he has given. In any case, `Enum` is a special case because the subclasses of `Enum` are created by the language and are forced to subclass `Enum` with the exact generic parameter of themselves. That is not true of any other situation. You cannot force that in any other situation.

Comment: @newacct - actually, you can.  did you try it?  this is actually a very handy pattern.  i've used it in my code so i know it works.

Comment: If you have `class Foo extends AbstractMessageHandler<Foo>{ ... }` then you can have `class Bar extends AbstractMessageHandler<Foo>{ ... }`. So what really does this bound accomplish?

Comment: @newacct - i don't understand your question.  you're asking if you misuse the pattern, why is it useful?  misusing the pattern doesn't make it not useful.  typically, you don't use a concrete type in the bound until you get to the bottom of your class hierarchy.  you just continue the pattern on the intermediate classes.  obviously, picking some other random class for the bound isn't very helpful...

Comment: Generics is to make provable guarantees that avoid the need for cast. What cast does this recursive bound prevent?

Comment: @newacct - when used correctly, it allows superclass methods to return the subclass type (especially useful for builder-style classes).  see example [base type](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/sqlbuilder/apidocs/com/healthmarketscience/sqlbuilder/BaseCreateQuery.html) and [concrete type](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/sqlbuilder/apidocs/com/healthmarketscience/sqlbuilder/CreateIndexQuery.html).

Answer (score 0):

In your generic definition you can do `<T extends SomeClass>`

For example:

```
abstract class Processor<T extends String> {
    abstract T process();
}
```

In your case, it looks like `T` should extend some `Response` class, and not `AbstractMessageHandler`.

Comment: Note: he is in the first line. He is hitting some other issue.

Comment: Yeah, he added that while I was writing it.

Answer (score 0):

From the code given, it doesn't seem like there's any need to make the class generic. How about a generic method instead (I've even made it static, as it doesn't seem that you need to use the current object at all):

```
public abstract class AbstractMessageHandler
{
    public static <T extends AbstractMessageHandler> T setResponseValues(AbstractMessage request, T response )
    {
        response.setCompanyId(request.getCompanyId());
        response.setMessageGroup(request.getMessageGroup());
        response.setUserId(request.getUserId());
        response.setTimeStamp(AbstractMessage.getCurrentTimeStamp());

        return response;
    }
}
```

Or even better, just define a method on AbstractMessageHandler that operates on the current object. Then you don't need this static method, and you don't have this weird parameter that you always return.

```
public abstract class AbstractMessageHandler
{
    public void setResponseValues(AbstractMessage request)
    {
        setCompanyId(request.getCompanyId());
        setMessageGroup(request.getMessageGroup());
        setUserId(request.getUserId());
        setTimeStamp(AbstractMessage.getCurrentTimeStamp());
    }
}
```